# Is it possible to set different values for same formcontrol while looping (*ngFor) in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new to Angular 5 .I need to loop a form control along with other fields .While looping the DIV section I need to set different values for the form control.

Here I have List of employee name and their positions .While looping the JSON data using *ngFor I need to set different positions for each employee.

HTML.

```
 <div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor='let positionsEMP of Response'>

  <h6>{{positionsEMP?.Name}}</h6>

  <form [formGroup]="Employees" >
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Position</mat-label>
      <mat-select  placeholder="position"
        formControlName="position">
        <mat-option>Select</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let pos of POSITION" [value]="pos?.Id">{{pos?.Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="Employees.get('position').hasError('required')">
        EMployee name is must.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>

  <button  class="col-sm-12" mat-flat-button (click)=Action(positionsEMP?.ID,Employees.value)>Update</button>
</div>
```

Here I want to set different values to the form control for the respective employee.

TS.

Comment: please check the below stackblitz and whether it will answer your question or not

Comment: @where it is ..@Sheik Althaf

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-formss?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: In my case I want to loop a mat-select (dropdown) with different values @SheikAlthaf

Answer (score 0):

In the typescript you probably have:

```
this.Employees = this.fb.group({
"ID"       : [""],
"position" : [""]
})
```

If you want to change the value of a `formControlName` when you click update then do the following:

```
Action(id,value)
{
 this.Employees.controls["ID"].setValue(id); 
 this.Employees.controls["value"].setValue(value);
}
```

**Note:**

The variable name and the method name should always start with lowercase letter, check: [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)